# e2e testing and $timeout

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

In my app I have a $timeout that fires every minute and schedules another $timeout. Because of this my e2e tests wait for $timeout and don't want to work at all. As I understand there is no way to say karma not to wait for certain $timeout. But is there a way to detect that code is running in karma environment and don't run this $timeout at all?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any elegant solution. For now I decided to pass a flag in a url, parse it and disable this special $timeout depending on this flag. This solution doesn't look good but it works. I hope later angular will have some kind of e2e dsl commands for this kind of things.

Answer (score -2):

From AngularJS [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout):

> In tests you can use $timeout.flush() to synchronously flush the queue
>   of deferred functions.

If you call many $timeouts, you can use the **waitsFor** jasmine function. Something like this:

```
waitsFor(function () {
  $timeout.flush();

  return workedThreeTimes();
}, 'should run something per minute', 1000 * 60 * 3);
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Is it possible to inject something in e2e tests?

Comment: Yes, you can use inject() function:

it('should inect something', inject(function ($timeout) {
  expect($timeout).toBeDefined();
}));

Also you need to use anguar-mocks.js

Comment: Thanks. By the way do you have some stable example of karma-runner configuration for e2e with jasmine.js and angular-mocks.js. I spent a few hours trying to combine it but still have different error messages. For instance "TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitsFor' of null" if I try to flush $timeout in waitsFor block

Comment: I am using yeoman with angular-generator - it provides easy way to configure angular application.

Comment: I have tried it a few months ago. That time they had only unit tests runner. Do they add e2e in a latest version?

Comment: Docs also say that there's only one mock available for e2e tests - the e2e $httpBackend mock: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E. Also you can NOT use inject function in e2e tests.